# Is the usage of 'for getting warm' correct here?

Tags: phrase-usage

> X sat near the fire ***'to get warm***' or '***for getting warm***'.

I think both are correct. If this is not the case, could you explain why?

Comment: We usually see and use the expression like "X sat near the fire to warm himself/herself up". But the first of your suggestion seems natural as well.

Comment: Of the two you quote to get warm is much more natural.

Comment: to get warm is regular speech. To warm oneself is literary or formal. That said, it is to in either case.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "sat near the fire for getting warm", is not natural. The expression "sat near the fire to get warm" is the usual expression.
The phrase "to get warm" is a to-infinitival used as an adjunct of purpose. One sits near the fire for the purpose of getting warm.

The phrase "for getting X" can be used in other contexts, but not for purpose. For example, it can be used in the sense of "because of":
*He was scolded for getting sassy with the teacher.*